# Named implementations - Why is @{myOrd} placed before parameters?

Tags: idris

In the following code, why is the `@{myOrd}` placed before his parameters and not after?

```
[myOrd] Ord Nat where
  compare Z (s n) = GT
  compare (S n) Z = LT
  compare (z z = EQ
  compare (S x) (S y) = compare @{myOrd} x y
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

`compare`'s type is `Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering`, so the choice of `Ord a` implementation is passed as the first argument.

`compare x y` is syntax for using the unnamed `Ord Nat` implementation, by filling in the implicit `Ord Nat` argument based on `x` and `y`'s type.